# Next book in learning Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, self-learning

I have just finished the book "C C Pinter - A Book of Abstract Algebra". My aim is to reach to the level of the book "T W Hungerford - Algebra". Hungerford's book is not only too advanced to study after Pinter's, but also I don't think that it is a readable book at all for a self-learner like me. Please someone tell me a book for abstract algebra more advanced than Pinter's book but readable esp. for self-learning . Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might want to try Dummit and Foote. It covers [roughly] the same material as Hungerford (a phenomenal text, BTW), but is about 3 times bigger, i.e. it is much more "wordy."

Comment: It seems exactly what I was looking for. However, I need to study to see it; and thank you so much.

Comment: I concur in your judgement of Tom’s graduate-level book: it’s a fine reference book but a lousy text.

Comment: @rnrstopstraffic I studied the book Dummit and Foote you suggested. It's a brilliant text. Thank you very much. If you move your comment to answer I will 'accept' it.

Comment: @AlphaE I'm glad that worked out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try Dummit and Foote. It covers [roughly] the same material as Hungerford (a phenomenal text, BTW), but is about 3 times bigger, i.e. it is much more "wordy."

Answer (score 1):

A very good book would be J. B. Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*.  It contains very good exercises and the concepts are clearly explained